# Grails- <g:link> inside <g:link>

Tags: html, grails, gsp

I have dropdown with list of people results.
Each result contain some details.
The demand is that click in each  `<div class="list-item clearfix">`will redirect the user to specific change ' unless the user click on some inner span ( `<span class="locationJob">`) which redirect him to another page.

```
<div class="list">
    <g:each in="${peopleList?.getResults()}" var="doc">
        <div class="list-item clearfix">
            <g:link controller="connection" action="details" id="${ApplicationUtils.encodeString(doc.ref?.toString())}">
    <div class="avatar">
<span class=""><img src="${doc.avatarUrl}" width="41" alt="Avatar" class="img-circle"/></span>
</div>
<div class="info">some text</div>
<div class="row no-margin body highlight-search-term">
<span class="locationJob">
<g:link controller="profile" action="show" id="${ApplicationUtils.encodeString(profExperienceCompanyIds[index]?.trim())}" class="professional-exp-highlight">
    {currentCompany}</g:link>
</div>
</g:link>
</span>
</div>
</g:each>
</div>
```

I understood that it's not correct to  write  inside  .... So what should I do?

Comment: what does it have to do with grails? a plain html question

Comment: just make everything as link 1, except some inner span, that will be link 2

Answer (score -1):

You can replace inside g:link, use input type with onclick method to run remoteFunction: 
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html

Comment: Don't use any of the `remote` tags. They are old, going away, and not going to be in future versions of Grails.